# Tracing polygon with holes for Vector based flood fill

Tags: java, android, algorithm, flood-fill

I am writing some software that draws vector images and I am trying to implement a paint bucket/flood fill algorithm. My approach to doing this is one learned from inkscape's implementation where I will

1. take a bitmap snapshot of my drawing surface
2. do a traditional 4 connected flood fill
3. trace the resulting polygon and create a vectorized version of the filled area

The flood fill algorithm is straightforward enough, but I have not found a good solution to trace the polygon if the polygon has holes. I have seen [this site](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html) which suggests that I should run a hole finding algorithm on the polygon and then run a countour tracing algorithm on the results. However, I cannot find a good resource on a hole finding algorithm. Anyone know the names of algorithms that I could implement or find a library on to solve this problem?

If it helps, I am programming in Java (Android)